Tesseract - Use in Browser Console
I am trying to use Tesseract within the browser console. This is for a site for which is not my own so I cannot embed external scripts for security reasons, hence why I run my code in the browser console. However, it is only for personal use and for intention of reading data from a canvas image.
I embedded the JS from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@5.0.5/dist/tesseract.min.js' and then ran the following from the examples page of Tesseract GitHub pages:
(async () => {
const worker = await createWorker('eng');
const ret = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
console.log(ret.data.text);
await worker.terminate();
})();

Which produces the following error (also because of security issues.): 'VM11097:6 Uncaught (in promise) Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@v5.0.5/dist/worker.min.js' failed to load.'
Is it possible to compile the Tesseract JS files into a single block of code? Essentially, I want to bypass anything which involves referencing an external source.
Many thanks, greatly appreciated.

first of all, that seems you want to using tesseract library.
So, before anything you should import it into the browser, to achieve this, run this code:
import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@5.1.1/dist/tesseract.esm.min.js').then((tesseract) => {
    // your code goes here
});

Then, you need to createWorker. To use it, you can use this code:
import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@5.1.1/dist/tesseract.esm.min.js').then((tesseract) => {
    const createWorker = tesseract.default.createWorker;
});

And finally, your code should be convert to this:
import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@5.1.1/dist/tesseract.esm.min.js').then(async (tesseract) => {
    const createWorker = tesseract.default.createWorker;
    const worker = await createWorker('eng');
    const ret = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
    console.log(ret.data.text);
    await worker.terminate();
});

Because you used await, I convert the callback method to async.
I hope this helps you!
